# How to get payload value from quick replies on Facebook Messenger

Tags: python, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to get the payload from the quick replies that I'm using to create a chatbot on Messenger, but I keep getting this error: KeyError: 'quick_reply'. I am using python to create bot. I've tried everything imaginable such as:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  data = request.get_json()
  log(data)

  if data["object"] == "page":
    for entry in data["entry"]:
        for messaging_event in entry["messaging"]:
            if messaging_event.get("message"):


                recieved(messaging_event)

                message_text = messaging_event["message"]["quick_reply"]["payload"]

            if messaging_event.get("delivery"):
                pass

            if messaging_event.get("optin"):
                pass

            if messaging_event.get("postback"):
                pass

  return "ok", 200
```

But each one keeps giving me the same problem. I've looked online and at docs but there seems to be no answer. Any insights?

Comment: Can you post the full code, including where messaging_event is set?

Comment: Yea here is my full code @amuramoto

Comment: Are you certain that the quick reply is what's being received and not a message echo or some other event? Try changing the conditional `if messaging_event.get("message"):` to `if messaging_event.message.get("quick_reply"):` to ensure you're only entering that block when it's an actual quick reply that's received.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately it didn't work @amuramoto I'm just not sure why I can't get the payload

Comment: You've verified that when you gate with `if messaging_event.message.get("quick_reply")` your code enters that block? If that's the case, I'd check that `quick_reply` is an object and not a string for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you! @amuramoto

Comment: What did it turn out the problem was?

Comment: @amuramoto I had to put the quick reply statement inside of if "text" in event["message"], which was another part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

When a Quick Reply is tapped, a text message will be sent to your webhook Message Received Callback. The text of the message will correspond to the title of the Quick Reply. The message object will also contain a field named quick_reply containing the payload data on the Quick Reply.

so quick reply payload will be like message.quick_reply.payload